# SNS - Getting badge count of devices in a Topic

Tags: ios, swift3, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

If you were to publish to 3 devices in a Topic, how can you get an accurate badge count for each of those 3 devices and pass them through?

e.g.

- Device A - unread messages 3
- Device B - unread messages 5
- Device C - unread messages 10

If i publish a message through to the Topic, each device gets the same payload including the same badge number.

Is it possible to somehow upon receiving the push notification, be able to handle the badge number correctly (if app is in the background) somewhere in the AppDelegate?

Or is the only way to get the correct badge number is sending a message via direct messaging? i.e. instead of sending to a topic, you send to individual device tokens.

Answer (score 0):

> Publishers send messages to topics. Once a new message is published, Amazon SNS attempts to deliver that message to every endpoint that is subscribed to the topic.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/PublishTopic.html

When you publish to a topic, you can supply different formats, but not different messages.  All subscribers get the same message.  Individualized messages have to be sent directly.